# How to format the contents of an email message generated by Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

I have created a contact form on my website with Angular 8 and I need to format the generated email message.

```
// send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
    server.send({
      text:   
      'Order details:\n First Name: ' + req.firstName +
                '\n Last Name: ' + req.lastName +
                '\n Email: ' + req.email +
                '\n Phone: ' + req.phone +
                '\n Notification: ' + req.notification +
                '\n Order Types: ' + req.orderType1 + ', '  + req.orderType2 + ', ' + req.orderType3 + ', ' + req.orderType4 +
                '\n Servings: ' + req.servings +
                '\n Occassion: ' + req.occassion +
                '\n Date of Occassion ' + req.dateOfOccassion +
                '\n Date of Application ' + req.dateOfApplication +
                '\n Theme: ' + req.theme,
      from:    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      to:      "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      cc:       req.email,
      subject: "testing emailjs"
    }, function(err, message) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err || message);
      } else {
        return console.log('email was sent successfully');
      }
    });
```

This is the message format, However I need to add HTML tags to style it properly. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: you can add HTML tags to message body in email. but confirm that the api accepts html tags in string. if you want to design the body you have to write inline css or also send the `<style>` section in message body.

Comment: Can you provide an example on that?